# Deserialize complex nested json in Script Component SSIS WITHOUT using newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, ssis, json-deserialization, script-component

I am trying to deserialize complex nested JSON in Script Component SSIS WITHOUT using newtonsoft. This is how far I have reached. Thanks for any help.

Deserialize complete JSON

Example of my JSON file:

[{
"studentId":A2336,
'"Name":{
"FirstName":"John",
"LastName":"Doe"}
}
{
"studentId":B1470,
'"Name":{
"FirstName":"Mary",
"LastName":"Smith"}
}
]

//current code

```
Public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
{
      String jsonFileContent = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\desktop\sample.json");
      javaScriptSerializer js = new javaScriptSerializer();
      List<Student> allStudents = js.Deserialize<List<Student>>(jsonFileContent);

      foreach(var student in allStudents)
          {
               Output0Buffer.AddRow();
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Student Id is: " + student.studentId.ToString());
               //how to print the first and last name
         }
}

Class Student
{
Public String studentId { get; set;}
Public Name Name  get; set;}
}


Class Name
{
Public String FirstName { get; set;}
Public String LastName { get; set;}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Also, does your current code not work?  If so, where and how is it failing?

Comment: @dbc : I put in my code but Serge's answer solved it for me. Thanks again for looking and me and showing the right way to ask questions here. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
MessageBox.Show("First name: " + student.Name.FirstName);
MessageBox.Show("Last name: " + student.Name.LastName);
```